# powershell инициализация массива внутри if?

Tags: powershell

В конце приведён PowerShell скрипт. Логично предположить, что если вызвать с такими параметрами: `qwe folder1 folder2`, то он выведет в месте вывода папок `folder1, folder2`. Тем не менее вывод такой:

```
.\filterOn\setup <br>
.\filterOn\init<br>
.\filterOn\work<br>
.\filterOn\free<br>
folder1<br>
folder2<br>
```

при этом `ha-ha` не выводится.

на текущий момент пофиксил так:

```
 else { 
    $folders.Clear()  
    $args[1..($args.Length - 1)] | ForEach-Object {
        $folders += $_

    }
}
```

----------------------------

**Powershell скрипт**

```
if($args.Count -lt 1) {
   $pathToConnectionString = "..\..\wwwroot\CMS\web.config"
}else {
   $pathToConnectionString = $args[0]
}
Write-Output $args.Count
Write-Output ($args.Count -lt 2)
if(($args.Count - 0) -lt 2) {
    $folders = ".\filterOn\setup", ".\filterOn\init", ".\filterOn\work", ".\filterOn\free"
    Write-Output 'ha-ha'
} else { 
    $folders.Clear()  
    $args[1..($args.Length - 1)] | ForEach-Object {
        $folders += $_

    }
}

$folders | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output $_
}

Write-Output $folders.Count $folders.Length
Write-Output $pathToConnectionString

exit
```